Diagonalize reducible row stochastic matrix with Permutation matrix
Given a reducible stochastic matrix $A$, can I show that it can always been written as lower block diagonized matrix with some permutation matrix $P$?  Where
$A=P A P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
I_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & I_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\cdots &\cdots &\cdots &\cdots \\
0 & \cdots & I_r & 0\\
T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_{r+1} \end{pmatrix}$
where $I_i$ are irreducible matrices,  and $T_i$ are substochastic matrices, with $\sum_{i}\sum_m(T_i)_{nm}=1$
In other words, by permutating the states, I can group the state in different recurrent communicating classes, and the transient state are put in the end. Where $A_i$ are irreducible substochastic matrices describing the transition in each communicating classes, while $T_i$ describes how the transitent state and transit to other communicating classes?
Is there a general name for the diagonalized representation?
